# How to add alx support to recent mainline kernel?

Tags: 12.10, kernel, asus

Apparently [mainline kernel 3.8.5](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) is compiled without support for recent Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet card. I know it is supplied in recent kernels with the module name `alx`.

Compilation of [Driver Backports Wiki](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)

The backporting mechanism doesn't work here since and it fails during compiling (and no wonder, since it is written that it is compatible with no later than 3.6 kernels).

I could use [compat-drivers](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Documentation/compat-drivers), but they fail to build.

What are my options (except from recompiling the whole kernel) to add alx module?

(I need a recent kernel because I'm playing with btrfs).

By the way I use ASUS N56VZ notebook.

Update:

[Unified alx driver strategy attempt for Linux and FreeBSD](https://github.com/erikarn/alx) did compile, but it didn't install the driver. (No errors in process, but ultimately no network eighter.

I did put `sudo make linux-install` after compilation. But after reboot the the `alx` module is still not present.)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1) Try this ppa

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

You download the kernel you want to try and install it with dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.8.5-030805-generic_3.8.5-030805.201303281651_amd64.deb
```

change the name to the kernel you download. If you are building modules you will need the headers as well.

See also: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Note these kernels are intended for testing only and no support is available.

2) Compile a kernel yourself.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Once you build a few kernels it is not *too* hard. Start with localmodconfig and then check to see the alx module is going to be compiled.

http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/kernel#localmodconfig

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first option is exactly what _doesn't_ work. And precisely because the mainline kernel doesn't have this device I ever asked that question. And 2. I know that compiling would help, but it is impractical to recompile the kernel every few weeks, when new version is available. I just thought, that maybe because the Linux kernel has modular structure, there is a way to compile _only_ the driver itself. Just like with compat-drivers, except that they don't compile.

Comment: although you can compile just a single module, you would need to do so for each kernel. You do not "need" to compile a kernel every few weeks, stay with a working one. Last, on anything resembling a modern machine, with localmodconfig, compiling a kernel should take 10-15 minutes tops. Up to you, it is your hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Maybe indeed I see it the wrong way.